# Could i set a value by Traversing if i only have the $(selector)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

is it possible to set the **age** value, if i only have e.g the $(selector) value id=**three**?

I read something about "Traversing", but will this solve my problem?
How could i only change the value from the < td>age< /td> ?

```
<!--
// New added code to explain what i mean:     
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("three").children( ??? ).html("new age 40");
}); 
--> 



<table id="testtable" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="display:none">id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>lastname</th>
      <th>age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <span id="one">  
        <tr>        
            <td style="display:none">1</td>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td> 
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
    </span>

    <span id="two">
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none">2</td>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td> 
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
    </span>

    <span id="three">
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none">3</td>
            <td>Hans</td>
            <td>Smith</td> 
            <td>22</td>
        </tr>
    </span>

  </tbody>
</table>
<br> Selection:
<div id="selection">---</div>
```

example to edit on: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rule_34/uzua5jew/)

Comment: can you be more specific about requirements?

Comment: your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is assuming the third td element will hold the age. Not the best practice, but this is how you can do it.

```
$("span[id=three] td:nth-child(3)").val(newAge);
```

Or, you can also use the selector defined in the another answer : `"#three..."`

You can also attach data element to provide more information about the placeholder. Like:

```
<td data-element="age">22</td>
```

And then change your selector to be:

```
$("span[id=three] td[data-element=age])").val(newAge);
```

Comment: Sorry, your example is not working. I tried to attach the "data-element".

Comment: @Bettelbursche the attaching didn't work or the selector?

Comment: You have two typos here, `newage` not `newAge`. And `tr[id=two] td[data-element=age])` have a redundancy round bracket at the end. And use html() to change value, val() doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @Bettelbursche changed a few thing, you can test it now http://jsfiddle.net/m1sxmtg0/

Comment: Thx Hp93, now i see the bracket. After changing now it´s working: http://jsfiddle.net/rule_34/nbhrkgd2/13/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `n-child` selector:

```
$("#three>tr>td:nth-child(4)").html(someValue);
```

Read more at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

By the way I don't think you should put a `span` inside a `tbody` tag. Instead just set the id of `tr` tag.

Comment: I have changed my code to: <tr id="three">. After this $("#three>td:nth-child(4)").html(newAge); is working.